# Split a string, parse it to int and assign to a different variables

Tags: javascript, node.js

I need to read from file some numbers
`input.txt // [1,2,3] [4,5,6] 5 10`
and assing them to variables
`a = 1, 2, 3`
`b = 4, 5, 6`
**a** and **b** must be arrays of numbers
`c = 5`
`d = 10`
There is where i stuck:

```
const fs = require('fs');

var [a, b, c, d] = fs.readFileSync('input.txt', 'utf8').split(' ');

console.log('a:' + a + '\nb:' + b + '\nc:' + c + '\nd:' + d);
```

Console:

```
a:[1,2,3]
b:[4,5,6]
c:5
d:10
```

All variables are strings.
What should I do next? Do I need to parse every variable separatly or there is some other fancy solutions?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) along with [Array.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) for this:

```js
let input = "[1,2,3] [4,5,6] 5 10";

let [a,b,c,d] = input.split(" ").map(e => JSON.parse(e));

console.log(Array.isArray(a));
console.log(Array.isArray(b));
console.log(a);
console.log(b);
console.log(c);
console.log(d);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do that simply by parsing the values as JSON like so:

```
var [a, b, c, d] = fs.readFileSync('input.txt', 'utf8').split(" ").map(a => JSON.parse(a));
```